# Непонятки с CHMOD

Tags: php

Вопрос такой: есть скрипт (файл-менеджер).
Проблема в том, что с помощью скрипта не могу поменять chmod - пишет

> Warning: chmod() [function.chmod]: Operation not permitted in /home/bla bla bla........

Через Командер ставлю атрибуты 0777 на все файлы и каталоги которые "курирует" скрипт. Всёровно не помогает.

Но, с файлами и каталогами созданные самим скриптом - проблем нет.
На сколько я понимаю - проблема с ЮИД владельца. Но я же ставлю атрибуты Командером - -0777 (типа без ограничений.....) и всёравно не пашет.

Да, кстати! Пробылал chown() - тож выдает Operation not permitted.

Подскажите люди добрые - как бороться с этим "Нафиг" ?

Comment: заходишь по root-ом?

Comment: Ну, если через фтп-командер можно удалять и создавать всё что угодно - то наверное. И админка привязана к тойже уч.записи..

Comment: Апач запущен от имени того же пользователя, что и фтп-сервер?
Директория, где лежат ваши файлы, должна принадлежать пользователю от имени которого запущен Апач. Естественно ему для записи нужны будут права.

Answer (score 1):

Стандартная ситуация например на мастерхосте. Веб-сервер работает от **www-data**, скрипты соответственно тоже, а вот ФТП/SSH работает от **u123143**. Помимо этого, у PHP может быть включен например safe mode или же стоять umask.

Если у вас есть две диретории www/mydir и у директории www владелец не www-data ( что чаще всего бывает ) то изменить какие-либо атрибуты списка файлов внутри этой директории скорее всего не получится. В любом случае - тут верно подметили, надо сделать два файла ( директории ) из скрипта и консоли и посмотреть ls -la

Answer (score 0):

В php не силён, но видимо вам следует поменять владельца/группу для всех директорий где он работает с файлами на пользователя от которого идёт исполнение. С помощью команд `chown`, `chgrp`.

> Да, кстати! Пробылал chown() - тож выдает Operation not permitted (((

Такое может быть, если директория уровнем выше не доступна для записи. Вас следует либо поменять владельца и выставить не менее `rwx------`, либо просто выставить `rwxrwxrwx` чтобы писать мог кто-угодно, что не рекомендуется.

Comment: Ниччо не помогает(((( 
Самое смешное, что сам скрипт может грохнуть любой файл или директорию со всем ее содержимым, НО прав на смену прав - нету )))
Директория в которой находится скрипт - на следующим уровне от корня и у нее 0777

Comment: А может в php запрещены эти функции?

Comment: это хотя бы linux?

Answer (score 0):

Создай файл из под командера и создай файл скриптом. Посмотри кто владелец каждого файла. Я думаю из под командера у тебя будет root, а скриптом возможно наверное владелец под именем "аппач" или ещё как-то. У меня была такая трабла. Пришлось писать хостеру чтоб открывал доступ на двух владельцев управлением всех файлов